# Como fazer que a saída do console apareça em um textArea no WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria de saber uma forma em que a saída do meu projeto, apareça em um textArea no WindowsForms. Preciso disso pois meu sistema é um conversor de números binários, e quero que imprima na tela o passo a passo do calculo. Se existir outra forma, aceito sugestões!

Exemplo de método:

```
public int ConverterDeBinarioParaDecimal(String numeroBinario)
    {
        double resultado = 0;
        int qtdDigitos = numeroBinario.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("xxx = {0}", qtdDigitos);

        for (int cont = 0; cont < qtdDigitos; cont++)
        {
            if (numeroBinario[cont] == '1')
            {
                resultado = resultado + Math.Pow(2, qtdDigitos - (cont + 1));

            }
        }

        int resultadoConversao = Convert.ToInt32(resultado);

        return resultadoConversao;
    }
```

Comment: Qual é o problema em substituir os `Console.WriteLine` por `MessageBox.Show` ou `TextBox1.Text` ? Uma vez que é windows forms faz sentido usar as coisas apropriadas nesse contexto. `Console`, como o próprio nome indica, é para aplicações modo consola.

Answer (score 1):

Um console só exibe o log do executável, seria complicado você redirecionar a saída do stream do Console para um TextBox (isso não é impossível, mas é chato). Há uma simples linha de código que permite você fazer a mesma coisa:

```
public static void WriteLn (string text, params string[] args)
    => TextBox1.Text += "\n" + String.Format(text, args);
public static void WriteLn (string text)
    => WriteLn (text, new string[] { });
```

Para usar, é só substituir

```
Console.WriteLine("xxx = {0}", qtdDigitos);
```

por:

```
WriteLn("xxx = {0}", qtdDigitos);
```

> Observação: altere o nome do controle `TextBox1` caso for necessário.